# Toggle Value of One Item in an Object Using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

**SEE UPDATE AT END OF QUESTION**

**ALSO SEE THE 2ND UPDATE**

I have a simple object with two items (although it may very well grow to more):

```
const initialValues = {

  noLabels: false,
  useFormik: false,
}
```

I now want to use React Hooks to be able to toggle the values of a given item in that object.  The way that this will work is that I will check whether or I have set a prop.  If the prop is set, then I want to toggle the value to true.  If it is not set, then I'll keep it as false.

For example:

```
<Form noLabels>
...
</Form>
```

This would set `noLabels` to `true`.

I am trying to figure out how to write a simple function that will do this **without** having to write a bunch of `else if` statements.

So, I want a simple function that looks something like this:

```
const toggleValues = setValues(props.value = !props.value)
```

Of course, `prop.value` won't work.  What I would like to know is what would work.  What should I put inside the `setValues()` function so that I can toggle the relevant item in the object?

**UPDATE**

My question is based off a context that I am creating.  Here is the code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const FormContext = createContext()

const initialState = {
  noLabels: false,
  formik: false,
}
export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)


  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ ...values }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

What I want to do is add a `toggleValues` function -- something like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const FormContext = createContext()

const initialState = {
  noLabels: false,
  formik: false,
}
export const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

const toggleValues = setValues({...values, XXXXXXXX })

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ ...values, toggleValues }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I am trying to figure out what to put in XXXXXXXX.

**SECOND UPDATE**

---

I am trying to find a solution that does **not** require me to specify the names of the keys of the object.  Rather, something that will automatically look at the props name on the `Form` component and check them against the keys of the object.  If they match, then they'll toggle that item.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. A hook to update the initial Values based on a prop change? Could you please elaborate better?

Comment: @Dupocas I updated the question.  Please take a look and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `useEffect`, for example, a side-effect for `noLabels` change:

```
const initialValues = {
  noLabels: false,
  useFormik: false
};

const CustomForm = ({ noLabels, useFormik }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ noLabels, useFormik });
  }, [noLabels, useFormik]);

  return <Checkbox checked={values.noLabels}>noLabels</Checkbox>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [labelIsOn, setLabelIsOn] = useState(true);
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <CustomForm noLabels />
      <CustomForm noLabels={labelIsOn} />
      <Button onClick={() => setLabelIsOn(p => !p)}>Toggle Label Is On</Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should work for your case

````
  const [ innitial, setInitial] = useState({
  noLabels: false,
  useFormik: false
  })

  function toggle() {
    setInitial(props ? {...innitial, noLabels: true} : {...innitial, noLabels: false})
  }


```

Then you can tie the toggle function to your form
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that don't have to specify a key to toggle in toggleValues function. Just pass which key value you want to toggle when invoke toggleValues.

I also created a custom hook, and added the initial state and toggleValues function in it. to separate the logic.

[View on CodeSandbox](http://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-dream-e3c21)

```
const initialState = {
  noLabels: false,
  useFormik: false,
  toggleValues: () => {}
};

function useForm() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const toggleValues = name => {
    setValues(value => ({ ...value, ...{ [name]: !value[name] } }));
  };
  return [values, toggleValues];
}

const FormContext = createContext();

const FormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [values, toggleValues] = useForm();
  const { noLabels } = values;
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider
      value={{ ...values, toggleValues }}
    >
      {children(values, toggleValues)}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <FormProvider>
      {(values, toggleValues) => {
        const { noLabels } = values;
        console.log(values);
        return (
          <>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={noLabels}
              onChange={() => toggleValues("noLabels")}
            />
            {noLabels || <label>noLabels</label>}
          </>
        );
      }}
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```